# Install Go Raspberry pi for Github project

Tags: go, raspberry-pi3

Hi so installed talkiepi from [Github.talkiepi][1] in 2018 installed and worked fine.
In 2021 iv installed latest version of Stretch and followed the steps but hit into an error.

When i do `go get github.com/dchote/gopus` I get the following error.
package math/bits: unrecognized import path "math/bits" (import path does not begin with hostname)

I been searching on line and going true other posts about this issue and some people are saying it because of Go version 1.7

my issue is when i do `apt-get install golang libopenal-dev libopus-dev git`
My only option is version 1.7

Iv tried to manualy install later versions using the following.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.14.4.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.4.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
rm go1.14.4.linux-arm64.tar.gz

Step 3: Configure Go

Now you just need to configure it, which you have to do with any Go installation anyway.

Open up your ~/.profile (Using nano, vi, etc)

vi ~/.profile

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

But i cant get it to work with the github talkiepi

```
As root on your Raspberry Pi (sudo -i), install golang and other required dependencies, then build talkiepi:

apt-get install golang libopenal-dev libopus-dev g
su mumble
mkdir ~/gocode
mkdir ~/bin
export GOPATH=/home/mumble/gocode
export GOBIN=/home/mumble/bin

cd $GOPATH

go get github.com/dchote/gopus
go get github.com/dchote/talkiepi

cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/dchote/talkiepi

go build -o /home/mumble/bin/talkiepi cmd/talkiepi/main.go
```

NEWTESTS

```
    wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.17.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
    
    rm -rf /usr/local/go && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.17.linux-armv6l.tar.gz

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

its installed in usr/local

```
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ mkdir ~/gocode
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ mkdir ~/bin
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ export GOPATH=/home/mumble/gocode
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ export GOBIN=/home/mumble/bin
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ cd $GOPATH
mumble@raspberrypi:~/gocode $ go get github.com/dchote/gopus
bash: go: command not found
mumble@raspberrypi:~/gocode $ go install github.com/dchote/talkiepi/cmd/talkiepi@latest
bash: go: command not found
```

==================================Friday 03/08/2021=================
So i went with a fresh install of Stratch Os for the Raspberry pi
did a full update and then a reboot. I have installed the latest go go1.17.linux-armv6l.tar.gz.

Install go   using this [links][2]

```
nano go_installer.sh
```

enter the following shell scripts and save the file.

```
export GOLANG="$(curl https://golang.org/dl/|grep linux-armv6l|grep -v beta|head -1|awk -F\> {'print $3'}|awk -F\< {'print $1'})"
wget https://golang.org/dl/$GOLANG
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf $GOLANG
rm $GOLANG
unset GOLANG
```

Next make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x go_installer.sh
```

To run the shell script, type:

```
./go_installer.sh
```

Final Step - Setup path

```
nano ~/.profile
```

Scroll all the way down to the end of the file and add the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
GOPATH=$HOME/golang

source ~/.profile

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ go version
go version go1.17 linux/arm
```

Now to install Talkiepi

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo -i
root@raspberrypi:~# adduser --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos "" mumble

root@raspberrypi:~# usermod -a -G cdrom,audio,video,plugdev,users,dialout,dip,input,gpio mumble

root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get install libopenal-dev libopus-dev git

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

root@raspberrypi:~# su mumble
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ export GOPATH=/home/mumble/gocode
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ export GOBIN=/home/mumble/bin
mumble@raspberrypi:/root $ cd $GOPATH
bash: cd: /home/mumble/gocode: No such file or directory
```

SO Go not in the correct directory how can i move it.
[1]: https://github.com/dchote/talkiepi/blob/master/doc/README.md
[2]: https://www.e-tinkers.com/2019/06/better-way-to-install-golang-go-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Get a current version of Go, then check the intro docs again to see how modules work.

Answer (score 1):

The Go project supports only the two most recent major Go releases. (As of today, that is Go 1.17 and Go 1.16.7.) To install a supported release, see https://golang.org/doc/install.

Note that recent versions of Go enable module mode by default. To install the `github.com/dchote/talkiepi/cmd/talkiepi` binary in module mode (without defining your own module), you can run:

```
$ go install github.com/dchote/talkiepi/cmd/talkiepi@latest
```

---

That said, the fact that `apt-get` is installing Go 1.7 suggests that the Linux distro installation on your Pi is also very old. You may want to also check out [Updating and Upgrading Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/os.html#updating-and-upgrading-raspberry-pi-os).

Comment: Hi i get the following 
bash: go: command not found i have made an edit to my original post showing what i did.

Comment: It looks like you are missing an entry in your `PATH` environment variable. Did you follow all of the instructions in section 2 of https://golang.org/doc/install#install?

Comment: Yep i followed the steps forgot to add it in Stackoverflow sorry. 1. Webget version 1.17     2. rm -rf /user/local      3.export PATH.  4.REBOOT 5. Go version      Said go not installed  but i can see the folders

Comment: Is the directory containing the `go` binary present in your `PATH`? (What is the actual value of `$PATH` in the shell, and what is the path to the `go` binary?)

Comment: I started all over again made a fresh install was able to get go install but new issues now. modified my original post

Comment: `GOPATH` is _not_ the directory in which the `go` command is installed. It is the directory in which the `go` command places downloaded source code. Run `mkdir -p $(go env GOPATH)` and then `go install github.com/dchote/talkiepi/cmd/talkiepi@latest` as above.